# identify and list all duplicate items in an array using jq

Tags: json, duplicates, jq

My requirement is 2 parts: 
    1 - extract all the IP address from a huge JSON file 
    2 - find and show only the duplicate values

```
I am able to achieve the first part but struggling to achieve the 2nd 
part.
```

After the part1, here is how I get the output

```
["4.2.1.9"]
["4.2.1.1"]
["4.2.1.9"]
["4.2.1.102"]
["4.2.4.131"]
["4.2.1.2"]
["1.23.39.33"]
["1.218.4.4"]
["4.2.1.2"]
["1.218.1.1"]
["4.2.4.19"]
["4.2.1.26"]
["4.2.4.58"]
["4.2.4.13"]
["4.2.4.29"]
["1.23.39.49"]
["1.23.39.241"]
["4.2.1.93"]
["4.2.4.54"]
["4.2.4.12"]
["4.2.4.50"]
```

So, from the above list, how can identify the duplicates and list them. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straightforward and efficient solution using the generic function:

```
# The given stream is assumed to consist of strings
def bagof(stream):
  reduce stream as $x ({}; .[$x] += 1);
```

`bagof` emits a JSON object that records the number of occurrences of the items in the given `stream`.

Since the given input consists of a stream of string-valued arrays, we can write:

```
bagof(inputs | .[0])
| with_entries(select(.value > 1))
| keys_unsorted
```

assuming that jq is invoked with the `-n` command-line option.

Since the given input is actually the result of some other operations, it should be easy to tweak things so that the above solution could be simplified a bit while still using the given def of `bagof`.